# .NET Core EF6 error with SQLite connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I can't seem to pass parameters to sqlite connection string ...

If I do:

```
 public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<MyData> MyData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=C:\\src\\mydb.db;");
    }
  }
```

Everything works fine. However if I change it to:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=C:\\src\\mydb.db;Version=3;");
```

Then queries throw `System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'version'.'`

or if I change it to:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=C:\\src\\mydb.db;Read Only=True;");
```

Then queries throw `System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'read only'.'`

what's wrong here ? how do I pass ie read only to sqlite ?

Comment: What database provider are you using?

Comment: how do I know which provider I am using ?? I do not have any using statement for Microsoft.Data.Sqlite ... I just used UseSqlite()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of the provider you are using certain keywords are not available. You can take a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/ for examples.If you are using [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0) then the connection string should use the keyword **Mode=ReadOnly**

From [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/406) reported issue:

```
We support the following keywords.

Keyword Values
Cache   Private or Shared
Data Source The database file. Can be a URI filename.
Mode    ReadWriteCreate, ReadWrite, ReadOnly, or Memory
```

Comment: The provider I use is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, I couldn't find relevant documentation but "Mode=ReadOnly;" worked ! thx